# MVC parameter-Routing is null

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have the following in my RouteConfig:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{caseID}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Generator", action = "Index", caseID = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

And my ActionResult method:

```
public ActionResult Index(string caseID) {
    //some code
    var currentcase = new Something.Read(caseID);

    //some other code
    return View(model);
}
```

My url looks like localhost/Generator/Index/dee7aff5-0a34-4965-936f-a08f1dae5c43

Now my caseID should be "dee7aff5-0a34-4965-936f-a08f1dae5c43" but it is null and i can't figure out why.

Can anyone help me?

**UPDATE**

If the url is

localhost/Generator/Index/?caseID=dee7aff5-0a34-4965-936f-a08f1dae5c43

instead of

localhost/Generator/Index/dee7aff5-0a34-4965-936f-a08f1dae5c43

it runs well.

Comment: Which version of MVC are you using?
I tested your code with MVC 5 and if I call the same URL you wrote, the action is called with the parameter correctly valued.

Or, are you sure that there are no other registered routes that could conflict with that? Your controller has a custom rule defined with a data attribute?

Comment: I am using version 5.2.3

Answer (score 0):

Replace CaseID with id in your route.config file hopefully it will work.And in your action as well with id